# Python add new rows with unique ID

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a project where I need to routinely add rows for new customers. Each customer needs a unique ID. The problem I currently have is developing a code that will recognize which ID's are already taken so there are no duplicates ID's.

Sample dataframe:

```
     ID     Name     Age     Location
0    123    Mark     32      Chicago
1    435    Tom      26      Nashville
2    544    Susan    54      Chicago
3    356    Frank    45      Cleveland
4    643    Myles    44      Chicago
```

On any given day I may need to append one or more rows for new customers. ['Name', 'Age', 'Location'] will be provided but I need to come up with a way to create a unique ID for each new customer. If anyone has ideas on how to accomplish this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Unique ID you use is totally up to you. Most people use a random number and cross-reference it to make sure it hasn't been used, or one seeded from data about the customer. You want to avoid anything too obvious as things like sequential IDs can cause security issues.

Comment: why dont you use uuid - https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html